# OS X Server vs Jenkins continuous integration server battle

Tags: android, ios, xcode, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am new to continuous integration and I was wondering if anybody has any input on what the best option out there is.

I am confused as to whether or not OS X Server is available for cross-platform dev (iOS + android). I know Jenkins is.

Also any other +'s and -'s on both would be appreciated as well. I would love to open up a debate on iOS continuous integration

Any input would be fantastic. Thanks in advance. Cheers!